# How to set a specific value at the end of struts 2 select element?

Tags: java, html, struts2

Here is an example, with set the value **Please_select_a_value** at the beginning of the rendered select list:

```
<s:select id="myGuiId" name="myGuiName" headerKey= "0" headerValue="Please_select_a_value" list="mySourceList" />
```

This generated the following HTML code:

```
<select name="myGuiName" id="myGuiId">
    <option value="0">Please_select_a_value</option>
    <option value="1">Value_1</option>
    <option value="2">Value_2</option>
    <option value="3">Value_3</option>
    <option value="4">Value_4</option>
    ...
    <option value="20">Value_20</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way, to set the value **Please_select_a_value** at the end of the rendered select list (if I open select list in GUI) without using some tricks in the correspondent Struts action class? Something like this in HTML code:

```
<select name="myGuiName" id="myGuiId">
    <option value="1">Value_1</option>
    <option value="2">Value_2</option>
    <option value="3">Value_3</option>
    <option value="4">Value_4</option>
    ...
    <option value="20">Value_20</option>
    <option value="21">Please_select_a_value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You could merge a new item into the list via OGNL (IIRC) but IMO it's a backwards UX.

Comment: could you post an small example, please?

Comment: Example of what? How to add item to list?

Comment: Clear violation of the [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) :)